# In WPF - XAML is there a way to bind to a property change behaviour without using UpdateSourceTrigger?

Tags: wpf, xaml, avaloniaui

I'm trying to code some  behaviours in WPF.
Consider the following code snippet:

```
<Button IsEnabled="{Binding Path=ButtonsAreEnabled, Mode=OneWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}">
```

Is there a way for me to achieve the behaviour: **UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}** without using **UpdateSourceTrigger**?

I'm attempting to port some existing WPF  definitions into **Avalonia UI** and **Avalonia** does not currently support **UpdateSourceTrigger**.

How would I do this?

Thanks,JohnB

Comment: Just remove the `UpdateSourceTrigger` from the `Button`.  Are you facing any issues in removing it from there code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The combination `Mode=OneWay` and `UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged` is pointless.

`UpdateSourceTrigger` only has an effect in `TwoWay` or `OneWayToSource` Bindings, where it controls when exactly the source property of a Binding is updated.

Besides that, setting `Mode=OneWay` is redundant, because the `IsEnabled` property binds `OneWay` by default.

So your Binding expression should simply be this:

```
<Button IsEnabled="{Binding Path=ButtonsAreEnabled}">
```

Or even shorter:

```
<Button IsEnabled="{Binding ButtonsAreEnabled}">
```

Comment: spot on! Thank you